# Twilio conversations with email channel

Tags: twilio, sendgrid, twilio-conversations

I'd like to have email as one of the channels used in Twilio conversations. From the docs I see that Twilio conversation supports SMS, WhatsApp and InApp chat. Wonder if there is any API or library to add email as option? I guess I can use Sendgrid and most probably need to handle email integration on my own back-end.

Answer (score 1):

Today, Twilio Conversations does not support email as a channel.

Comment: Is this still the case today?

Comment: Correct, still the case today.

Comment: What about today?